# Interrupt 19 capture bios option

Tags: boot, bios

What does it mean to enable `interrupt 19 capture`. The help text for this option reads: enable to allow the option ROMs to trap the interrupt 19.

Semi relevant:
Asus WS motherboard (intel z97).

Answer (score 11):

#### This is used by certain devices to intercept the normal boot process.

INT 19h (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_interrupt_call#Interrupt_table)) is a low-level system command normally used just after POST to boot the operating system. In typical end-user configurations outside of a business environment this setting may be ignored as it likely has no effect on your system.

Peripheral devices providing **[option ROMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_ROM)** such as network interface cards ([PXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment)) or RAID storage controllers may intercept this command to run code that is required to set up the boot media (e.g [RAID](http://www.techarp.com/showFreeBOG.aspx?lang=0&bogno=290)) before handing it over to the OS.

Comment: But still, one main question or THE main question for me about this remains just unanswered (to say: "Enable/Disable" is sure clear but as I know this setting from my current and previous boards, it's description/options are different: "BIOS reaction on INT19 trapping by Option ROM: IMMEDIATE - execute the trap right away; POSTPONED - execute the trap during legacy boot"): So, what does changing this setting result here in the end? I mean, the description is not bad and it exactly tells what it does. But I have no idea what this means to me, what happens/changes, what's the effect finally?!?